# Given points AB, BC and CA find point A

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

**Question:**
AB=(0,-2,1), BC=(0,1,-5), CA=(0,1,4) find A

**What I've tried so far:**
I know that AB=B-A, so I tried making a system of equation with the known points, however that doesn't seem to be working because I recursively come back at the same equation where there is one more unknown point.

Comment: Notice that the sum of these vectors is a zero vector. You don't know the coordinates to any of the points, only the distance from the starting point. You can move the starting point around and it would still work. The problem has no solution -- you can actually set any coordinates that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If these are, as your "AB=B-A" relation indicates, vectors based at first letter going to second, like AB means vector starting at A and ending at B, then the individual points A,B,C are not determined, because any three values x,y,z could be added to the three coordinates of each of A,B,C without changing any of the differences A-B,B-C,C-A.